# How can I get a Botswana visa from Nigeria

Tags: visas

Am from Nigeria and I work on cars planning to move to Botswana how can I get the visa ?

Comment: You apply through your nearest consulate or embassy. Details [here](http://www.gov.bw/en/Ministries--Authorities/Ministries/Ministry-of-Labour--Home-Affairs-MLHA/Tools--Services/Services--Forms/Application-for-work-permit/). But somehow I don't think that's all you're asking.